# Using a date for a datetime field in a SOQL Query

Tags: soql

The [SF doc](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm) explains how to put a Datetime query in a SOQL query.

```
SELECT Id
FROM Account
WHERE CreatedDate > 2005-10-08T01:02:03Z
```

I need to just put in a date for this query. Something like:

```
SELECT Id
FROM Account
WHERE CreatedDate > 2005-10-08
```

But that throws an error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

CreatedDate is a datetime field so I guess you would need to specify the time component.

Can you do something like where you just append the time portion to be 12 am by default.

```
WHERE CreatedDate > 2005-10-08T00:00:00Z
```

Or you can use Date Literals like

```
 WHERE CreatedDate > YESTERDAY
```

For more on date formats and more literal values see,

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm

Comment: The advice in another answer to use "DAY_ONLY()" is the correct answer.  Otherwise a developer would have to write, "where createddate >= yyyy-mm-ddT00:00:z and createddate < yyyy-mm-ddT00:00:00z" where the second date is actually the day after the first (or some similar bounded comparison).

If had had to choose (and I just did today), I would use DAY_ONLY().  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_date_functions.htm

Comment: Note that "where createddate >= yyyy-mm-ddT00:00:z and createddate < yyyy-mm-ddT00:00:00z" can use the index on CreatedDate, but DAY_ONLY() cannot.  For a very large table, it maybe preferable to use NOT use DAY_ONLY.

Answer (score 37):

To filter a SOQL query on a datetime field with a day value, use the `DAY_ONLY` SOQL operator.

```
SELECT Id
FROM Account
WHERE DAY_ONLY(CreatedDate) > 2005-10-08
```

You can bind a date variable into the SOQL Query as well, but the [results might not be what you expect](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/4799/594) as there the date variable would be cast into a DateTime type at run time.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to avoid date manipulation with Apex, you could also create a custom date formula field and query off that field. Your formula would look like this:

```
DATEVALUE(CreatedDate)
```

Then just query off your custom field.

Let me know if you have any questions.