# Convert datetime to date in SOQL query

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, datetime, date

I have an Object (aObject) contains datetime field, I want to get all data from aObject where datetime includes 12-29-2013 ignoring the time.

any idea ?

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8896/using-a-date-for-a-datetime-field-in-a-soql-query?rq=1                          duplicate of the above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options for doing this directly in the SOQL query.

If you know the date you want to use "Literally" you could use a date literal:

```
select id,name from aObject where datetimefield = YESTERDAY;
```

Or, you would have to use a range of datetime values:

```
enter DateTime startOfDT = DateTime.newInstance(2013,12,29,0,0,0);
DateTime endOfDT = DateTime.newInstance(2013,12,29,23,59,59);
List<Case> cases = [
    select id from Case 
    where createdDate >= :startOfDT 
    and createdDate <= :endOfDT];
```

Comment: If you need to convert Datetime instance to a string literal use `<Datetime instance>.formatGMT('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss\'Z\'');`