# How to Apply a DateTime Filter when using SOQL via REST API

Tags: soql, datetime, rest-service

I'm working on a ASP.NET application which is calling our salesforce org via REST API. There is a feature to search data based on time period(`DateTime` field) as follows.

1. Today
2. Yesterday
3. Last 7 days
4. Custom selection (this is where I'm struggling)

Previously all filters were implemented by creating appropriate `DateTime` instance in `.NET` end and passing it to the query string. But the **Time Zone** difference is impacting the search results which I can understand. 
Then first three filter criteria were implemented with [SOQL Date Literals](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/officetoolkit/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm) and looks working fine. But for the last option I should take user input and create the `fromDate` and `toDate` in `C#`, then pass into my query string.

```
"?q=SELECT my_fields FROM my_Object__c WHERE Date_Registered__c > " + DateTime.Parse(txtFromDate.Text.Substring(6, 4) + "/" + txtFromDate.Text.Substring(3, 2) + "/" + txtFromDate.Text.Substring(0, 2)).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.000Z") + " and Date_Registered__c < " + DateTime.Parse(txtToDate.Text.Substring(6, 4) + "/" + txtToDate.Text.Substring(3, 2) + "/" + txtToDate.Text.Substring(0, 2)).AddDays(1).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.000Z");
```

In this way I can't handle the time zone impact on my search results. So it's giving some unexpected results. There are so many [examples](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4799/how-to-filter-soql-query-on-a-datetime-field-for-a-date-range) to handle these when using `Apex`. But here it's for `.NET` and I found nothing useful. 
Any guidance appreciate. 
Thanks

Comment: FYI there is this convertTimezone mechanism (http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_convert_time_zone.htm) that may be of some help.

Comment: Thanks @KeithC. I was thinking how to use `convertTimezone` here if there is a way. But still no luck. Can't think of a way to handle `DAY_IN_MONTH(convertTimeZone(Date_Registered__c)) >25 and DAY_IN_MONTH(convertTimeZone(Date_Registered__c)) < 02` like scenario when the `fromDate` and `toDate` are from different calendar months. I tried applying `CALENDAR_MONTH()`,`CALENDAR_YEAR()`,`DAY_IN_MONTH()` altogether.

Comment: Yes I couldn't think of how to use it; just wanted to make sure you knew about it given the problem is time zone related.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DAY_ONLY()` [Date Function](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_date_functions.htm) resolved the headache. Since it's no need of filter based on the time, we can add the range by taking only the day, if it's possible with `SOQL`. `DAY_ONLY()` is giving that as follows.

`DAY_ONLY(convertTimeZone(Date_Registered__c)) > 2013-11-01T00:00:00.000Z`

So below query is working fine for such situations.

```
"?q=SELECT my_fields FROM my_Object__c WHERE DAY_ONLY(convertTimeZone(Date_Registered__c)) > " + DateTime.Parse(txtFromDate.Text.Substring(6, 4) + "/" + txtFromDate.Text.Substring(3, 2) + "/" + txtFromDate.Text.Substring(0, 2)).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.000Z") + " and DAY_ONLY(convertTimeZone(Date_Registered__c)) < " + DateTime.Parse(txtToDate.Text.Substring(6, 4) + "/" + txtToDate.Text.Substring(3, 2) + "/" + txtToDate.Text.Substring(0, 2)).AddDays(1).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.000Z");
```