# Datetime representation in SOQL executed via REST API

Tags: soql, rest-api, rest, datetime, date

I am trying to execute below SOQL using Salesforce REST API using Postman

```
services/data/v36.0/query?q=Select Id from Opportunity  where CloseDate < 2016-07-31T04:17:54
```

But I am getting below exception

```
[
  {
    "message": "\nDAY_ONLY(CloseDate) < 2016-07-31T04:17:54\n                                        ^\nERROR at Row:1:Column:75\nline 1:75 no viable alternative at character '<EOF>'",
    "errorCode": "MALFORMED_QUERY"
  }
]
```

I don't get what is wrong with the query.

I referred [How to Apply a DateTime Filter when using SOQL via REST API](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/32150/how-to-apply-a-datetime-filter-when-using-soql-via-rest-api) and used DAY_ONLY function like below. But still got the same exception

```
services/data/v36.0/query?q=Select Id from Opportunity  where DAY_ONLY(CloseDate) < 2016-07-31T04:17:54
```

I've tried using the below formats of date, but of no use.

```
2016-07-31
2016-07-31T04:17:54
2016-07-31T04:17:54Z
2016-07-31T04:17:54.000
2016-07-31T04:17:54.000Z
2016-07-31T04:17:54.000+1:00
2016-07-31 04:17:54
```

What is I am missing over here?

Comment: Try `2016-07-31T04:17:54Z`.

Comment: @AdrianLarson- Tried and getting this error ```value of filter criterion for field 'CloseDate' must be of type date and should not be enclosed in quotes```

Comment: If you include time don't use `DAY_ONLY`. Otherwise drop everything before the `T`.

Comment: @AdrianLarson - Tried both. Still getting the same error :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `CloseDate` field is of the `Date` type. That means you should not include a time component in your filter value. This query works for me in the `Developer Workbench`. Should be the same for you in Postman, I'd think.

```
/services/data/v36.0/query?q=Select+Id+from+Opportunity++where+CloseDate+<+2016-07-31
```

Specifically, the date format is `2016-07-31`.