# SOQL DateTime Greater than Date

Tags: apex, soql, datetime

For the life of me I cannot figure out how to query tasks greater than a given DateTime. I have a field, inqDateTime, that I need to pull tasks greater than that date. [I have tried to convert the DateTime to a Date field](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F00000008wFbIAI), but then I get zero returns because it lacks the T and Z from the value, I guess?

So then [I tried to use the DAY_ONLY bit in the WHERE clause](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4799/using-a-date-for-a-datetime-field-in-a-soql-query-criteria?noredirect=1&lq=1), but I get errors like crazy expecting a `;` .

How do I use a DateTime field and get all tasks from that date?

---

For reference, here is my code:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static integer taskQuery(DateTime inqDateTime, id leadID){
    System.debug('militaryQuarantineController.taskCount running.............................................................');

    //Date inqDate = Date.newInstance(inqDateTime.year(), inqDateTime.month(), inqDateTime.day());
    DATE inqDate = inqDateTime.DATE();
    //String inqDate = DateTime
    System.debug('inqDate = ' +inqDate);
    List<Task> taskList = [SELECT id FROM Task WHERE whoid= :leadID AND TaskSubtype!='Task' AND ActivityDate >= : inqDate];
    System.debug('There are ' +taskList.size()+ ' tasks since the last inquiry');

    integer taskCount = taskList.size();

    return taskCount;
}
```

Comment: can you try this ?

`System.debug([SELECT id FROM Task WHERE  whoid= :leadID AND  TaskSubtype!='Task' AND  ActivityDate  >= : inqDateTime]); `

Comment: That will fail with a bind type error.

Comment: It is worth noting that when I run a query through workbench I get the values I expect. `SELECT ActivityDate,Id,TaskSubtype FROM Task WHERE ActivityDate >= 2018-11-02 AND TaskSubtype != 'Task'`

Comment: @PhilW the above query works at my end.

Comment: @PranayJaiswal since ActivityDate is a date field, it fails entirely. I have to convert it to a date field, but the conversion appends the time, which seems to make it fail either way.

Comment: @PranayJaiswal when I try your method I get this error: `Invalid bind expression type of Datetime for column of type Date`

Comment: @PranayJaiswal, if I do likewise and the type of the binding variable is Datetime then I get the exception "Invalid bind expression type of Datetime for column of type Date"

Comment: @Chance, something to check - is there a pattern to the records that are missing? Are they all on the same date? (I'm wondering if there is a time zone issue going on here)

Comment: @PhilW Two of them are on the same date, but the third is not. I even just now added a fourth with the date of today. Workbench has no problems getting the tasks.

Comment: @Chance are you executing the queries with the same user in workbench and in your Apex? Could sharing rules be coming in to play?

Comment: @Chance do you have the same query running in workbench? There's no issue in the syntax of using the date field here. It could be possibly the other parameters in your where clause.

Comment: Are you in Timezone? I am in GMT and ` [SELECT id FROM Task WHERE whoid= :leadID AND TaskSubtype!='Task' AND ActivityDate >= : inqDate];` works

Comment: @JayantDas .....ahhhhhhhh dang it. I am not passing the leadID correctly from the component. Well, at least now I understand what the issue is. Thank you and you should promote this as an answer.

Comment: Ooops! Shame about that, but great you have a solution.

Comment: @Chance I think you figured it out, go ahead and add that as an answer and elaborate as what was missing.

Answer (score 3):

It seems the problem was elsewhere in my query. I was not passing the leadID correctly after a couple of other edits. Check all your filters, kids.

For future reference, this will work:

```
DATE inqDate = inqDateTime.DATE();
List<Task> taskList = [SELECT id FROM Task WHERE whoid= :leadID AND TaskSubtype!='Task' AND ActivityDate >= : inqDate];
```